# How can I determine the status of a patent application?

Tags: pre-grant, us20100195872

I would like to know whether this patent application was granted or not.

How can I do that? Is there a way to check the status?

In reference to the patent: [US20100195872](https://www.google.com/patents/US20100195872)

Comment: Information I was given  EFS ID  19267363  Application Number  14302039  Confirmation Number  1696  Title of Invention  A METHOD, SYSTEM AND PROGRAM PRODUCT FOR MONITORING OF SLEEP BEHAVIOR  Customer Number or Correspondence Address  Filed By  Ariel S. Bentolila/Nadia Leach  Attorney Docket Number  NYSCJ01  Filing Date  Receipt Date  11-JUN-2014

Comment: Provisional application was then transitioned "option" to move onward for patent application filing status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know whether this patent application was granted or
>   not.

**Quick Info**

Every Patent application In US is provided with code tags which can be helpful to get quick information (not being final info) These can be following

**A1** - Published Patent Application (also to granted patented before year 2001)

**B1** - Patent

**B2** - Patent for which a earlier application publication was made.

Now to get exact information for patent STATUS Grant or not you need to visit respective patent office website wherein Patent Register is stored. For US Patent office it can be found in below link:-

[USPTO Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)

> How can I do that? Is there a way to check the status?

For Example:- For your query:-
[image]
Apart from Status Following info can be seen:-

1. Transaction History:- all patent related transaction notification
2. Image File Wrapper:- all document scan copies
3. Continuity Data:- all related patent applications (priorities)
4. Published Documents :- all related published applications
5. Address & Attorney/Agent:- patent agents or attorney details
6. Assignments:- any assignments made on application
7. Display Reference

Comment: Information I was given  EFS ID  19267363  Application Number  14302039  Confirmation Number  1696  Title of Invention  A METHOD, SYSTEM AND PROGRAM PRODUCT FOR MONITORING OF SLEEP BEHAVIOR  Customer Number or Correspondence Address  Filed By  Ariel S. Bentolila/Nadia Leach  Attorney Docket Number  NYSCJ01  Filing Date  Receipt Date  11-JUN-2014